# Order columns from a list of pre-defined names and ignore column names which don't exist in the list

Tags: r, data.table

I want to order a data.table by using a set of predefined names available in a list.

For example:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(mtcars)
list_name <-c("mpg", "disp", "xyz")

#Order columns
setcolorder(dt, list_name) #requirement: if "xyz" column doesn't exist it should ignore and take the rest
```

The use case case is that there are multiple data.tables that are getting created and all of them have column names from a list of names. There can be missing column names in some data but the data needs to be ordered as per a list.

```
output:

dt
     disp    wt  mpg cyl  hp drat  qsec vs am gear carb
 1: 160.0 2.620 21.0   6 110 3.90 16.46  0  1    4    4
 2: 160.0 2.875 21.0   6 110 3.90 17.02  0  1    4    4
 3: 108.0 2.320 22.8   4  93 3.85 18.61  1  1    4    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to load all of them in a `list` and then use `setcolorder` by looping over the `list` with `lapply` and use `intersect` on the `names` of the dataset while ordering

```
lst1 <- list(dt, dt)
lst1 <- lapply(lst1, function(x) setcolorder(x, intersect(list_name, names(x)))
```

---

If we need to reuse, create a function

```
f1 <- function(dat, nm1) {
        setcolorder(dat, intersect(nm1, names(dat)))
 }
f1(dt, list_name)
f1(dt2, list_name)
```

Comment: Hi @akrun, I will be importing the data at different sequence so I cannot wait till the  end to make them into a list. I have alist of names ad I want to order by them and export the data one by one.

Comment: @Deb If you are doing this one by one, can you use a function as in the updated solution

Comment: @Deb Also the list of names you mentioned - is it the object names i.e. `list("dt", "dt2", ...)`  etc?  If that is the cause you can use `mget` i.e. `lst1 <- mget(unlist(yourlistofnames))` and use the first code with `lapply`

Comment: the names were actually column names but thanks for this clarification too. helps a lot!

Comment: @Deb with `data.frame/data.table/tibble`, `names` refer to colnames and that is not the case for `matrix`